# No HDMI audio on Mint (IntelHD5500)

Tags: linux-mint, audio, hdmi

I'm new to linux world, I've installed Mint 18 with Cinnamon desktop, but I have a problem with audio over HDMI neither on my monitor or TV here is kernel, and list of audio devices:

```
 ~ $ uname -r
4.6.0-040600-generic
 ~ $ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3235 Analog [ALC3235 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I hope I can get some help here as I couldn't find any solution for Intel on google

If there is some other commands which could help please type them, I'm really new and don't know much yet.

Comment: Did you check if you could get any sound from the sound adapter directly (speaker or headphone)?  Did you try simply playing a basic music file like a mp3?

Comment: It works on laptop build-in speakers and when I plug-in headphones, but still won't work on HDMI, nor mp3 nor Firefox

Comment: There is a little update after a month: I have it fixed somehow, don't really know how, but now there is a problem with docking station, I cannot get audio working over HDMI output of Docking Station, have somebody seen this issue?

Comment: These issues could be as simple as a bad connection.

Comment: What do you mean by bad connection? There is only problem with sound over HDMI from docking station, everything else, like audio jack, USB ports, and video over HDMI is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Sound and video are on different connectors with HDMI, so a bad cable could do that.

Comment: Cable is ok I'm using it to connect laptop and TV without docking station and it's working fine, with docking station there is a problem that alsa won't recognize digital HDMI audio output